# Website not displaying properly after publishing to GitHub pages

Tags: github

I made changes to a forked repository and served the website successfully on my desktop. However, after publishing the repository to GitHub pages, the website is not displaying properly.
I followed the steps in the GitHub pages documentation.

https://github.com/aolayeye/aolayeye.github.io

Website not displaying properly:

[image: website not displaying properly]

Website on local:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This not a simple html pages website, Your app is not detected by git hub. So only your index.html file is displayed.

Git hub servers are bit slower, So may be your static files are not displayed.

Suggestions - Use vercel.com  for fast deployment and it's also beginners friendly.